# Can a presure sensor work under resin?

Tags: arduino, sensor

I want to make a lamp without a switch, just a pressure sensor under resin and an Arduino.

Can the pressure sensor work under the resin?

Comment: Probably not but what details have you provided to make an assessment?

Comment: You might be better off using a capacitive sensor instead.

Comment: It'll tell you what the pressure is within the resin. If the resin is flexible, and doesn't interfere with the operation of the sensor, this might work. If it's rigid, obviously it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends entirely on the resin and the sensor.

- Some resins are hard, rigid materials when cured and nothing inside
  them would respond to outside pressure. Some are quite flexible or
  "rubbery" and would transmit pressure, though the response of the
  sensor might well be quite different than a "bare" pressure sensor.
- Some sensors have the sensing element physically shielded in various
  ways that might not be very compatible with working when
  encapsulated.